# Is there any suggestions to Monitor results? for Store and load instructions implemented using Data Memory

Tags: architecture, verilog, display, instruction-set

I am having difficulty in getting the Load and store instructions implemented in my Processor. I have Successfully implemented ALU RegisterFile now i want to add A Data Memory and Upgrade the Control unit. I don't have yet implemented the instruction Memory. So instructions are hard coded in InstructionReg as 32 bits.
I want check weather load and store instructions work properly. So i Monitored data_write data_read and toReg with the changes in the clock. But i don't get results. Can you please help me with any error in the code. Or can you suggest me any method to do this. Hope the code is clear if there is any unclear thing please comment i can explain

> my results
>
> executing loadImmediate clk = 0 DataIn=  17 ReadData=   x toReg= 17
>   clk = 1 DataIn=  17 ReadData=   x toReg= 17 executing store clk = 0
>   DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 1 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x
>   toReg=  x executing load clk = 0 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
>   clk = 1 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 0 DataIn=   x
>   ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 1 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
>   clk = 0 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 1 DataIn=   x
>   ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 0 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
>   clk = 1 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 0 DataIn=   x
>   ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 1 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
>   clk = 0 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 1 DataIn=   x
>   ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 0 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
>   clk = 1 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 0 DataIn=   x
>   ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 1 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
>   clk = 0 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 1 DataIn=   x
>   ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 0 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
>   clk = 1 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 0 DataIn=   x
>   ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 1 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
>   clk = 0 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x clk = 1 DataIn=   x
>   ReadData=   x toReg=  x

```
<pre><code>
module testbed;

    //this is test bench

    reg clk, reset,rst;
    wire [31:0] instruction;
    wire [2:0] out_addr1, out_addr2, in_addr, select;
    wire [3:0] ReadAddr;
    wire data2_compli_control, immediate_control,busy_wait,memRead,memWrite,regWrite;
    wire [7:0] dataIN, dataSRC1, dataSRC2, dataSRC2_COMPLI, data2, data1, immediate_value,toReg,address,read_data,write_data;

    PC myPC(clk, reset,busy_wait, ReadAddr);
    regInstructions myRegInstr(clk, ReadAddr, instruction);
    CU myCU(busy_wait,instruction, out_addr1, out_addr2, in_addr, select, data2_compli_control, immediate_control, immediate_value, memRead,memWrite,regWrite,address);



    regFile8x8a mREG(clk,busy_wait, in_addr, toReg, out_addr1, dataSRC1, out_addr2, dataSRC2);
    CMPL myCMPL(dataSRC2, dataSRC2_COMPLI);
    MUX mMUX_C(dataSRC2, dataSRC2_COMPLI, data2_compli_control, data2);
    MUX mMUX_I(dataSRC1, immediate_value, immediate_control, data1);
    MUX mMUX_regWrite(write_data, read_data, regWrite, toReg);
    alu mALU(write_data, data1, data2, select);
    data_mem mdata_mem(clk,rst,memRead,memWrite,address,write_data,read_data,busy_wait);
    initial
    begin

        //$dumpfile("wavedata.vcd");
        //$dumpvars(0,testbed);

        clk = 1'b0;
        reset = 1'b0;
        rst = 1'b0;
        rst = 1'b1;
        //$monitor("DataIn = %d", write_data);

    end

    always #50 clk = ~clk;

    initial
    begin
    $monitor("clk = %d write_data= %d read_data= %d toReg=%d",clk,write_data,read_data,toReg);
        #5000 $finish;

    end

endmodule

module PC (

    input clk,    // Clock
    input reset,
    input busy_wait,
    output [3:0] Read_addr

);

reg [3:0] Read_addr = 4'b0000;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if(~reset)
        begin

            Read_addr <= Read_addr + 1'b1;  
        end

    else if (busy_wait) begin
        Read_addr <= Read_addr ;
    end
    else begin
        Read_addr <= 4'b0000;
    end

end

endmodule

module regInstructions (
    input clk,    
    input [3:0] Read_Addr, 
    output [31:0] instruction

);

reg [31:0] instruction;

                   //  00000000                         op_code
                   //          00000000                 destination
                   //                  00000000         source 2
                   //                          00000000 source 1
reg [31:0] step1 = 32'b00001000000001000000000000010001;        // loadi 4, X, 17
reg [31:0] step2 = 32'b00000101000000000000000000000100;        // store 0, X, 4
reg [31:0] step3 = 32'b00000100000001010000000000000000;        // load 5, X, 0
reg [31:0] step4 = 32'b00000001000001100000010100000100;        // add   5, 5, 4
//..............///
 /*reg [31:0] step5 = 32'b00000010000000010000010000000101;     // and   1, 4, 5
 reg [31:0] step6 = 32'b00000011000000100000000100000110;       // or    2, 1, 6 
 reg [31:0] step7 = 32'b00000000000001110000000000000010;       // mov   7, x, 2
 reg [31:0] step8 = 32'b00001001000001000000011100000011;       // sub   4, 7, 3*/

always @(negedge clk) 
begin
    case (Read_Addr)
        4'd0:instruction = step1;
        4'd1:instruction = step2;
        4'd2:instruction = step3;
        4'd3:instruction = step4;
        /*//...............////
         4'd4:instruction = step5;
         4'd5:instruction = step6;
         4'd6:instruction = step7;
         4'd7:instruction = step8;*/
        default : /* default */;
    endcase
end

endmodule

module CU (

    input busy_wait, //new
    input [31:0] instruction,
    output [2:0] OUT1addr,
    output [2:0] OUT2addr,
    output [2:0] INaddr,    
    output [2:0] select,
    output data2_compli_control,
    output immediate_control,
    output [7:0] immediate_value,
    output memRead, //new
    output memWrite, //new
    output regWrite, //new
    output [7:0] address

);

reg select, OUT1addr, OUT2addr, INaddr, data2_compli_control, immediate_control, immediate_value,memWrite,memRead,regWrite,address;

always @(instruction) 
begin
    memRead = 1'b0;
    memWrite = 1'b0;
    select = instruction[26:24];
    INaddr = instruction[18:16];
    OUT1addr = instruction[2:0];
    OUT2addr = instruction[10:8];
    immediate_control = 1'b0;
    immediate_value = instruction[7:0];
    data2_compli_control = 1'b0;
        case (instruction[27:24])               //new
        4'b0100:
            // load from memory 
            begin
                memWrite = 1'b0;
                memRead = 1'b1;
                address = instruction[7:0];
                $display("executing load"); 
            end

        4'b0101:
            begin
                memRead = 1'b0;
                memWrite = 1'b1;
                address = instruction[23:16];
                $display("executing store");
            end                     
            // store to memory
        4'b1000:
            // load
            begin
                immediate_control = 1'b1;
                $display("executing loadImmediate");        
            end 

        4'b1001:                        
            // sub
            // use the 2's comp
            data2_compli_control = 1'b1;
            //$display("oper = SUB");
        default : 
        begin
            memWrite = 1'b0;
            memRead = 1'b0; 
        end



    endcase

end

endmodule

module regFile8x8a (
    input clk,  
    input busy_wait,        //new
    input [2:0] INaddr, 
    input [7:0] IN,
    input [2:0] OUT1addr,
    output [7:0] OUT1,
    input [2:0] OUT2addr,
    output [7:0] OUT2
);

reg [7:0] reg0, reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4, reg5, reg6, reg7;

assign OUT1 = OUT1addr == 0 ? reg0 :
              OUT1addr == 1 ? reg1 :
              OUT1addr == 2 ? reg2 :
              OUT1addr == 3 ? reg3 :
              OUT1addr == 4 ? reg4 :
              OUT1addr == 5 ? reg5 :
              OUT1addr == 6 ? reg6 :
              OUT1addr == 7 ? reg7 :
              0;

assign OUT2 = OUT2addr == 0 ? reg0 :
              OUT2addr == 1 ? reg1 :
              OUT2addr == 2 ? reg2 :
              OUT2addr == 3 ? reg3 :
              OUT2addr == 4 ? reg4 :
              OUT2addr == 5 ? reg5 :
              OUT2addr == 6 ? reg6 :
              OUT2addr == 7 ? reg7 :
              0;

always @(negedge clk) //new
begin
    if (!busy_wait) begin
        case (INaddr)
        3'b000:reg0 = IN;
        3'b001:reg1 = IN;
        3'b010:reg2 = IN;
        3'b011:reg3 = IN;
        3'b100:reg4 = IN;
        3'b101:reg5 = IN;
        3'b110:reg6 = IN;
        3'b111:reg7 = IN;
    endcase 
    end

end

endmodule

module CMPL (
    input [7:0] Data,    
    output [7:0] out    
);

reg out;

always @(Data)
begin
    out = ~Data + 8'b00000001;
end

endmodule

module MUX (
    input [7:0] Data1,    
    input [7:0] Data2, 
    input control,
    output [7:0] out    
);

reg out;

always @(Data1, Data2, control)
begin
    case (control)
        1'b1:out = Data2;
        default :out = Data1;
    endcase

end

endmodule

module alu(out, DATA1, DATA2, Select);

input [7:0] DATA1, DATA2;
input [2:0] Select;
output [7:0] out;
reg out;

always @(DATA1, DATA2, Select)
    begin
    //$display("opcode = %b" ,Select);
    case(Select)
    3'b000:out = DATA1;
    3'b100:out = DATA1; //new
    3'b101:out = DATA1; //new
    3'b001:out = DATA1+DATA2;
    3'b010:out = DATA1 & DATA2;
    3'b011:out = DATA1 | DATA2;
    default:$display("Err in OpCode");
    endcase
    //$display("op = %b => %b %b = %b",Select, DATA1, DATA2, out);
end
endmodule

module data_mem(
    clk,
    rst,
    read,
    write,
    address,
    write_data,
    read_data,
    busy_wait
);
input           clk;
input           rst;
input           read;
input           write;
input[7:0]      address;
input[7:0]      write_data;
output[7:0]     read_data;
output          busy_wait;

reg[7:0]     read_data;
reg busy_wait,clkMem=1'b0;
integer  i;

// Declare memory 256x8 bits 
reg [7:0] memory_array [255:0];
//reg [7:0] memory_ram_q [255:0];



always @(posedge rst)
begin
    if (rst)
    begin
        for (i=0;i<256; i=i+1)
            memory_array[i] <= 0;
    end
end

always #1 clkMem = ~clkMem;

always @(posedge clkMem)
begin
    if (write && !read && !busy_wait)
    begin
        busy_wait <= 1;
        // artificially delay 100 cycles
        repeat(10)
        begin
        @(posedge clk);
        end
        $display("writing to memory");
        memory_array[address] = write_data;
        busy_wait <= 0;
    end
    if (!write && read && !busy_wait)
    begin
        busy_wait <= 1;
        // artificially delay 100 cycles
        repeat(10)
        begin
        @(posedge clk);
        end
        $display("reading from memory");
        read_data = memory_array[address];
        busy_wait <= 0;
    end
end

endmodule

</code></pre>
```

Comment: what did you mean "*But i don't get results.*"? Which results did you expect and did not get?

Comment: i dont get write read data

Comment: this is a lot of code you provided. you need to be more specific in what your problems are. Your answer did not clarify anything.

Comment: executing loadImmediate
clk = 0 DataIn=  17 ReadData=   x toReg= 17
clk = 1 DataIn=  17 ReadData=   x toReg= 17
executing store
clk = 0 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
clk = 1 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
executing load
clk = 0 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
clk = 1 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
clk = 0 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
clk = 1 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x
clk = 0 DataIn=   x ReadData=   x toReg=  x

Comment: Displyed answer is like these....but i want to immedilately upload 17 to register file and use it with load and store instructions

Comment: Even thoughi i have uploaded the whole code. I have clearly stated THAT I WANT TO MONITOR THE LOAD AND STORE INSTRUCTIONS. SO I MONITORED read_data AND write_data (varible names) BUT THOSE RESULTS ARE NOT DISPLAYED. I have clearly mentioned it in my description.

Comment: you mentioned "data read" and "data write" in your description, which did not exist in your code. `$monitor` displays data when data changes. So, apparently, in your case no data got changed. As i mentioned, you have a lot of the code. It seems that you are shy in using clocks and it looks like you created lops and races in your data path. Start with small pieces of code and add to it instead of creating the whole thing at once and wonder where the issue is. Use debugging tools, waive forms, $display to understand what is going on in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing this the wrong way.

In order to debug HDL you should get yourself familiar with a waveform display. Not only can it show you the signals and the value of each at any time. But you can also see the temporal relations, what changed at what time, what is one or two cycles out.
You can search for values, set markers, zoom in and out, expand and collapse buses, change the number format between binary, hex, decimal etc. Some can also convert a value to an analogue format.

If your circuits get a bit more complex you might have to keep track of a few hundred signal. There is no way you can do that with just using text.

If your simulator does not have a waveform display, abandon it and find a different one.